# Formatting a TextBoxFor from Decimal to Dollar Amount

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, decimal

I have an amount field that I am pre populating. When I run the web app, it comes out as 125.4500. I tried to format it but I've had no luck.

Here is my PaymentModel:

```
  [Required]
  [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
  [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
  [Display(Name = "Payment Amount")]
  public decimal Amount { get; set; }
```

The `DataFormatString` seems to have no affect.

And my code on the form:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "makePaymentTextRight width90" })
```

I tried this:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => string.Format("{0:F2}",m.Amount), new { @class = "makePaymentTextRight width90" })
```

But that gave me this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Templates can be used only with field access, property access, single-dimension array index, or single-parameter custom indexer expressions.

How do I get this to format to 2 decimal places?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Wow, easy enough. Post that as an answer and I'll give you credit. Tyvm!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `DisplayFormatAttribute` is only respected when using the `EditorFor()` and `DisplayFor()` methods (using the inbuilt templates)

To format a value, use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.inputextensions.textboxfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.InputExtensions.TextBoxFor<code>2%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B</code>0%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B<code>0,</code>1%7D%7D,System.String,System.Object%29) of `TextBoxFor()` where the 2nd parameter is the format string

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, "{0:F2}", new { @class = "makePaymentTextRight width90" })
```